# How to disable email confirmation in gitlab

Tags: email, gitlab

I set up a gitlab server in ubantu14.4.3SLT

in my case, I want to set up a git server for local users so I do not need user to sign in with any email confirmation.

How can I disable email confirmation in gitlab? are there any api or something simple to disable it?

Comment: Can you check if https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/81e741af2445f1e403c02dc172a47ade641eed60/config/gitlab.yml.example#L55 would be enough?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a good answer. But ran across this and wanted to skip for a test instance I have. This is what I did(gitlab 10.1.0):

From the rails console:

```
User.all.each  {|u| u.confirmed_at = Time.now; u.save}
```